# adding loader form after main form

Tags: c#, forms

I'm about to finish a project and I decided to add a form that shows application logo before the main form is loaded. The problem is I'm not sure how to make the logo form display first and then load the main form. When I hide the main form and load the logo form, the main form shows up for a second, which is not what I want. I want the new form (logo form) show up for 3 seconds and then show the main form. What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project properties you can set splash screen - select form that you created for that.

Edit: image to help navigate to it: [img](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/7990/splasho.png)